# Парсер для XML файла с бд

Tags: php, база-данных, xmlparser

Всем привет! Буду признателен, если натолкнете меня на мысль, как выполнить это задание. Я новичок в парсинге, поэтому для меня здесь мало что понятно.

На ftp сервер проекта раз в сутки выгружается XML-файл с данными по стоку. С каждой новой выгрузкой данные меняются - одни данные могут обновиться, другие добавиться, третьи удалиться (их не будет в новом XML-файле). Необходимо разработать архитектуру БД на основе XML-выгрузки и написать парсер XML-файла.
Парсер должен:
добавлять в базу записи, которых в ней еще нет;
обновлять записи, которые пришли в XML и уже есть в базе;
удалять записи из базы, которых нет в XML (чистить таблицу перед парсингом нельзя).
Парсер должен запускаться через консольную команду. При вызове консольной команды должна быть возможность указать путь до локального файла выгрузки, при этом, если путь до файла не указан, то берется дефолтный файл.
При проектировании архитектуры БД необходимо учитывать, что по всем полям, кроме id и generation_id , будет происходить фильтрации данных.

Answer (score 0):

1. Берете XML файл, смотрите его названия полей и что в них(строка, цифра, дата), создаете такой же набор полей в БД.
2. Если там сложный файл и какие то теги имеют потомков, их надо создавать в отдельные таблицы, а у родителя должен быть внешний ключь к ним.
3. У родительского тега вероятно есть уникальный идентификатор, его в БД называете каким нибудь `ExternalId`. Если такого нет, его надо придумать из составных частей других данных, важна уникальность.
4. По полям, которые будут участвовать в where надо создать индексы.
5. Гуглите что то подобное "php parse xml file".
6. При вычетке XML файла уже в коде PHP проверяете наличие `ExternalId` у себя в базе. Аля: `select count(*) from someTable where ExternalID = ExternalIdFromFile`. Если запрос возвращает больше 0 значит запись есть нам ее записывать не нужно.

Если у вас 0 знаний PHP и такой же 0 sql у вас ничего не получится, эту задачу "методом тыка" не решить.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ! Очень информативно. Знания php и sql есть, так что справлюсь

Comment: @DDDovi если ответ вам подошел отметьте его как правильный.